# How to prove that the simple product of two triple products may be expanded in terms of dot products?

Tags: vectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIk3a.jpg)The vector algebra gets heavy after few steps. Can someone give me a hint as to how to start proving that because I dont think I am doing it right.

> Prove that
>   $$ (A\cdot B\times C)(a\cdot b \times c)
> = \left| \begin{matrix} A\cdot a & A\cdot b & A \cdot c \\
> B\cdot a & B\cdot b & B\cdot c \\
> C\cdot a & C\cdot b & C\cdot c
> \end{matrix}\right|. $$

That s my try.

Comment: Can you use the [Laplace's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace's_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix)? If not you can apply the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: You say that you don't think that you are "doing it right."  It would be helpful to know what you *are* doing.

Comment: By the way what is the difference between the signs $\times $ and $\huge{\cdot} $ in this context? A reply is welcomed. We need to see some activity from you.

Comment: x vector product, ⋅ dot product

Comment: @Dalibor Thanks for your comment. But is there a difference in this context between $(A\cdot B\cdot C)$ and $(A\cdot B\times C)$?

Comment: Rule of Sarrus sure.

Comment: Yes there is a difference.

Comment: @Dalibor Ah ok, i see. Just wait for an answer. It is a good idea to show what you have tried by yourself. It´s encouraging people to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand expression is linear and fully antisymmetric (that is, an alternating multilinear form) in $A$, $B$ and $C$. We know from the [theory of determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Transformation_on_alternating_multilinear_n-forms) that this implies that it's a multiple of the determinant of the matrix formed by $A$, $B$ and $C$. The same is true for $a$, $b$ and $c$, and the same is true for the right-hand side. Thus it follows that the two sides are multiples of each other, and the factor is readily checked to be $1$ by substituting the canonical basis for both triples.